# Correct syntax for multiselect option referencing

Tags: bootstrap-multiselect

I'm finding it impossible to find the correct syntax to programmatically check a radio button in a Bootstrap Multiselect. Examples I've seen use this syntax:

```
$('#taskpriority').filter("option[value='3']").prop('checked', true);
```

I'm not seeing any errors in Firefox Developer console and its seems correct but nothing is checked - the default first item remains selected. What is the correct syntax? I've read there is a known bug but I don't know of the fix??

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar trouble.  According to documentation (http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#methods) options are selected like this:

```
$('#example-select').multiselect('select', ['1', '2', '4']);
```

Seems simple enough, but isn't working for me. Maybe it'll work for you though?